# Exponential distribution and Markov chain problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, exponential-distribution

A, B and C student arrive at the beginning of a professor's office time. The duration of time they will stay is exponentially distributed with means of 1, 1/2,and 1/3 hour.
I want to find the probability they are the last student left for each student and the expected time until all three students are gone.

I tried to transform it into a problem of Markov chain. We may denote the state of the Markov chain by the rates of the students that are left and use $\emptyset$ denote an empty ofﬁce. We get the following matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
 -6 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 0 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -5 
  \end{pmatrix}$
How would one continue to do this problem? Are there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Markov chain here, since there is no change from one state to another one.

Formally, the problem is the following: take $X, Y, Z$ independent, with $X \sim \mathcal{E}(1)$, $Y \sim \mathcal{E}(1/2)$, $X \sim \mathcal{E}(1/3)$. Then

- The probability Student A leaves first is $\mathbb{P}(X=\min(X,Y,Z))$. This is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables) for exponential distributions.
- The expected time that all three students are gone is $\mathbb{E}(\max(X,Y,Z))$. Can you figure out how to compute this?

Comment: We can view this problem as Markov chain as alternative way to solve it?

Comment: A Markov chain is a process that moves at random between different states. What would the states be here?

Comment: @ Raoul We may denote the state of the Markov chain by the rates of the students that are left and use $\emptyset$ denote an empty ofﬁce.

Comment: So the states would be $0, 1, 2, 3$? To make this a Markov chain (or more precisely, discrete-time Markov process), you'd need to say that there exponential waiting times between each state. For instance, from 3 to 2, it would be the minimum of the three exponential times, which is indeed exponential $1 + 1/2 + 1/3$. But then what about from $2$ to $1$, and from $1$ to $0$? Is the waiting time independent of the previous one, and exponential? It seems a bit of a too complicated way to tackle this problem.

Comment: I meant "continuous-time Markov chain" or "Markov jump process", not "discrete-time", since this is clearly not discrete time.